# Replacing a word depending upon the previous and next word in a file using java

Tags: java

I have a SQL file in which I want to replace a word with something else. But the catch here is, I would replace the word depending upon the occurrence of the previous two words and the next word.

For example, If the SQL file contains `"INSERT INTO table_name VALUES"` then I just want to add a bracket to the table name and capitalize it.

so, after the changes, it would be `"INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] VALUES"`.

I have tried using `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` but I found that it might be not efficient in my case. The file has a lot of INSERT statements.

Please suggest some efficient idea for this.

Comment: What else do you need to replace besides this single example?

Comment: Maybe you want to use a regular expression: [`String.replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose you can't Upper Case the name of table with `replaceAll` :)

Comment: May I ask why you want to put brackets around the table name?  It should already run on SQL Server AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I have another doubt. In MySQL for carriage return and line break, we use '\r\n'. What do we use the same in MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Pattern` with this regex `(.*?\s+.*?\s+)(.*?)(\s.*)` or `((.*?\\s+){2})(.*?)(\\s.*)` like this

```
String query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?\\s+.*?\\s+)(.*?)(\\s.*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(query);
while (matcher.find()) {
    query = matcher.group(1) + 
            String.format("[%s]", matcher.group(2).toUpperCase()) + 
            matcher.group(3);
}

System.out.println(query);
```

Output

```
INSERT INTO [TABLE_NAME] VALUES
```

details :

1. `(.*?\s+.*?\s+)` match the two first words
2. `(.*?)` match the table name
3. `(\s.*)`

Comment: What did you mean @TimBiegeleisen ?

Comment: What I was trying to say is that if this replacement is going to be made on  a SQL query, the pattern probably has to be more specific than what you are using, lest unwanted replacements happen.

Comment: can you suggest another pattern @TimBiegeleisen you are better then me in this :)

Comment: The pattern I used seems fine to me, at least for this specific replacement.  But I hosed myself by giving a `replaceAll` answer where we can't change the case.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I have another doubt. In MySQL for carriage return and line break, we use `\r\n`. What do we use the same in MS SQL.

Comment: @PankajRathi please ask another Question, I'm sure that we will answer you :)